# Reverse lookup duplicate questions?

Tags: feature-request, search, duplicate-questions

Is there a way to search for questions which have been marked as a duplicate of another specific question?

I've been aware of a particular technical problem for some time.  I know for sure that other questions have been marked as a duplicate of [my original question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499485/how-do-i-use-swap-space-for-emergencies-only).  For my own (niche?) reasons I'd like to search for and read through some of the duplicate questions.

I'd like to explore duplicate questions to see if there's any useful nuggets of information which may have been otherwise buried.  I'd also like to collate a list of other similar issues or circumstances leading to the same symptoms.